# How to use Angular 9 navigation bar with router-outlet outside the app.component

Tags: javascript, angular, navigation, angular9, router-outlet

I'm a beginner in angular.I have created a navigation bar and this is my code inside the app.component

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
       <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
       <a routerLink="/register">Register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This works fine as follows
[Routing to logging component when logging is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfRa9.png)

[Routing to register component when register is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aJtB.png)

But when I select another component in my route the navigation bar still exists.So I need my nav bar with logging and register only in my Home component.It should not exist when I routes the other components.I think if i write my code inside another component except the app.component it will work.But how can I use router-outlet and everything on another component.Please help with example.
How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

in app.component.html
add  to

```
<nav *ngIf="isHomePage" class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
```

in app.component.ts -> ngOnInit()

```
this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
 if (e instanceof RouterEvent) {
   this.isHomePage = e.url.split('/').includes('home');
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.